# textcolor plugin tinymce codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, tinymce

I insert into a codeigniter app an editor with tinymce. It works good but it doesn't load textcolor plugin. I check in plugins folder and it is inside it. I also loaded it in the code:

```
$("textarea.tinymce").tinymce({
                // Location of TinyMCE script
                script_url : "<?=base_url('assets/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js');?>",

                // General options
                theme : "modern",
                plugins : "pagebreak,layer,table,save,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,textcolor,template",

                // Theme options
                theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
                theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
                theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
                theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak",
                theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
                theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
                theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
                theme_advanced_resizing : true,

                // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
                template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
                external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
                external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
                media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js"
            });
```

On firebug console I don't get any error.